# How to abstract the idea of themeable components?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, software-design

I'd like to make certain components of my program themeable by the user such that they can edit values in a settings user interface, such as background color, stroke, or size, and those changes will be reflected once they use that component in the software.

The solution would be simple if the values being changed were always the same, but they are not, as different components may have different "themeable" properties.

I would like to abstract this solution so that a themeable component can either extend a parent Component class who will have the property changing functionality.

My current idea is to create an abstract property class with an update method that returns a boolean and takes a String. For example, if someone was themeing a button, it may have a border property. The update method is defined such that it knows how to update the border based on a String, and the user would be interacting with a UI that knows what Strings to provide based on user input.

```
public abstract class XProperty
{
    public abstract boolean update(String info);
}
```

I'm sure there is a better or more simple way of doing this. What is the best way to design this functionality?

Comment: Let's say that you have 10 buttons and 10 windows. Do you want to be able to change the theme for only one button or one window or should the theme change be for all component's of a particular type? Also, providing a contract for updating components makes sense but how do you actually plan to update the components once the user saves a setting? You will probably have to redraw the component again right?

Comment: @bot In an MVC like setting, we are themeing differently for every view. The components will not be used outside of their view, because that's just the nature of this program. I have developed a way to do this using properties that the user can update, and when rendering, the components render based on the contents of the properties.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on my understanding of the described problem.
You can start by having an interface called Themeable which will be implemented by UI components classes (i.e. background, border, etc.) that have something that can be changed The Themeable interface can look something like this:

```
public interface Themeable{

    public boolean update(String info);
}
```

After that the UI component classes can implement that to change various properties. An example of that can be the following:

```
public abstract class Background extends UIComponent implements Themeable{

    private Color color;

    public boolean update(String info){
         //update the color instance variable
         //based on the
```

In essence, your UI can have multiple of these UIComponent objects which have different implementations based on what they need to do and you can use this update method to give them new properties.
Hope that helps.